# Mimic 'Pick up Line 1' On Asterisk/SPA504G Phone System

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip, pbx

We have a customer who is using a new Asterisk phone system we set up for them using SPA504Gs and SPA500DS sidecars.  They want to mimic their old system, where once a call is picked up on an extension it can be placed on hold and picked up from anywhere without having to actively transfer it to a single phone.

For instance, person A picks up Line 1.  Person A pages all the phones to say there is a call available on Line 1 for Person B.  Person B needs to be able to pick that call up wherever they are.

We currently have the SPA504G's set up where Line 1 is the inbound extension, and Lines2-4 represent the DID's for the customer.  When a call is picked up off one of the DIDs it is only active on that phone, so that other callers could call into the DID.

We're unclear how to make it so the call can be picked up from anywhere, could be make a 'Parked Call' key on the sidecar that could old these calls somehow?  Is there an easier way that would actively mimic their old PBX more directly (where 'Line 1' was actually 'Line 1' everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature called call parking and it already present in most asterisk system

Or maybe you are reffering to call pickup(*8) - if so you have put same pickupgroup on all extensions.

Unfortanly no way say which system you have and how to enable it on your system.

Comment: After doing a bit more research we were looking for something that would be a good SLA (Shared-line Appearance) solution.  Our SysAdmin had tried that once before without good results, he said he felt like it was a bit of a 'hack' and since we are using a voip trunk over a fixed wireless connection the occasional packet loss messed up the SLA attempt.  We did end up going with a call parking solution by adding some 'Park Slot Extensions' to the sidecars and that seems to be good solution for our customer.

Comment: Read this http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SLA .Also you can use conferences. To prevent miss of packet use sip via TCP.